# Using platform specific httclienthandler?

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

In xamarin should I always configure the app to use the platform specific httpclienthandler or is it ok to use the default httpclienthandler.  I have read that you get better performance but I was just wondering if it is so much better that this should be a standard practice for all my xamarin apps.

Comment: Using the platform-specific requires only changing the build options in each of the xamarin.ios|andorid application projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use `httpclienthandler` in the portable class library(pcl). Feel free to use `HttpClient` to run in a PCL library that supports iOS, Android, and WP8.

Here how i did it. Restart from a clean project.

Create a PCL with iOS, Android, .NET 4.5 and WP8. Add the microsoft Http nuget. It will install 2 other packages into the PCL.

Create the Android and iOS projects. Reference your PCL in both projects. For me that's all. It just works.
You may add the reference "System.Net.Http" in both platform projects. The reference is under Assemblies/Framework.

NEVER add Microsoft.Http nuget in any native project, nor the BCL nuget. It will create mess and you'll have to clean lots of things before it can work again.

It is extremely important that your NuGet manager is up to date, go to Tools-> Extensions and updates -> Updates